# How to store session in Redis from Spring application Java while using Load balancer?

Tags: java, session, spring-security, load-balancing

I am working on Spring project. We are using load balancer to handle 2 different nodes, sometimes I am getting session expired message. So in my google browsing I found we can store session in Redis and that will solve the problem.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession.html

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial

I am following these two links but there is no step by step procedure or how and where my session will store or how to add session details in Redis database.

Comment: Hope this example helps https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/samples/boot/redis

Comment: Hello Karthic Prasad, Thanks for your reply could you please give me a step by step procedure to do. Because i am new to Spring and this session conceps. and also i am not clear about redis.. so it would be good if there is a step by step tutorials